# categorical feature value in Neural Networks

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

Assume a neural network (NN) where each train example has a bunch of features and one of these features is the gender information (male or female).

Since it is a categorical data, I keep seeing things like:

```
If male, gender = 0
If female, gender = 1
```

When the NN is fed by input features, the result of (gender x any_weight) will always be 0 if the gender = male. And (gender x any_weight) will be equal to the value of the weight if the gender = female.

It looks to me like backpropagation's ability to update weights will be somehow limited because no matter how you change the weight, (gender x any_weight) will keep giving 0 if the gender = male.

And from this angle, it sounds like a better idea to say:

```
If male, gender = 1
If female, gender = 2
```

In this way, we make sure that the result of (gender x any_weight) won't be 0.

But I might be missing sth here because I keep seeing that categorization (in most cases) seems to start from 0.
Maybe someone having more experience here can clarify it better and explain what I am misinterpreting here?

Is using 0 and 1 the same thing as using 1 and 2? Or if not, which one should we go for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Categorical data is often encoded using one-hot encoding. So in your case `[1,0] if male else [0,1]`, you can think of a vector of zeros with only 1 at the given index. As such different "paths", weights will get activated based on what feature you have making it relatively easier for the network to use those features. Another way would be to encode it using -1 and 1, and there are other ways of [standardising data](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/01/01/how-to-standardize-data-for-neural-networks.aspx).

To answer your question, as far as a multi-layer perceptron is concerned it shouldn't matter, when the input is 0 the weights indeed would not be updated, but the hidden layers would be adjusted to recognise that, by recognise I mean you still have biases that would compensate for the 0 input (thanks for comment). Similarly when the input is 1,2 now the weights would adjust to differentiate between them. For binary data, -1,1 works nicely as it acts like a on-off for any weight. I would recommend you to try out your ideas and see what happens, there are nice [demos online](https://lecture-demo.ira.uka.de/neural-network-demo/?preset=Binary%20Classifier%20for%20XOR).

Comment: It's interesting to remember that even when weights are multiplied by zero, there is always the contribution of "biases". So, biases will play an important role for males, and weights will compensate the bias for females.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Both answers above make perfectly sense. Considering the impact of bias, it shouldn't hurt to set it to 0 an 1. But the value of weight is still useless for the case where gender=0. I also wonder one more thing then.. If a big portion of input features are categorical (that are either set to 0 or 1 (and maybe 2)), do you think how we set input features (as 0, 1, 2 or 1,2,3) would make a difference in the performance of NN (i.e. how quickly it learns or how well it converges with the same # hidden layers & units in each layer)?

Comment: When you have more than 2 classes then one-hot or variants make a big difference. When you have just 1,2,3 then your hidden layers have to learn how to chop the input space into 3 sub-spaces, whereas with one-hot they only need "select" one feature which you already separate out into different weights.

Comment: Many thanks for further clarification. Very valuable!